# How to add okhttp custom interceptor at runtime using bytebuddy?

Tags: java, okhttp, interceptor, byte-buddy, javaagents

I want to add my interceptor at runtime in okhttpclient, I am making Agent using bytebuddy in premain class. And i am trying to intercept the constructor of **"okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder"** to add my interceptor in the interceptors list.
But the problem is that the type() method is unable to find my class, I've tried different ways for eg: ElementMatchers .is(), .nameStartsWith(), .nameContains(), named() etc. but couldn't find the class.

I know that okhttp uses Kotlin & java adds **$** in the namespace to invoke some methods, so for my case i changed it to **"okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder"**, but again it was not finding the matching class.

I also want to know my approach that am i doing the right way to add the custom interceptor.

Agent:

```java
    public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

    new AgentBuilder.Default()           
          .type(ElementMatchers.named("okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder"))
          .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, javaModule, protectionDomain) -> {
                    System.out.println("Transformer: adding custom okhttpinterceptor using agent: " + typeDescription.getName());
                    return builder.constructor(ElementMatchers.takesArgument(1, OkHttpClient.class))
                            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(ConstructorInterceptor.class));
                })
          .installOn(instrumentation);
    }
```

ConstructorInterceptor:

```java
    public class ConstructorInterceptor {

         public static void doProceed(
            @SuperCall
            Callable<?> client,
            @Argument(0)
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient, @Origin String method) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Constructor Interceptor was called for: " + method);
        client.call();
        okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new HttpInterceptor());
    }
}
```

HttpInterceptor:

```java
    public class HttpInterceptor implements Interceptor{

      @NotNull
      @Override
      public Response intercept(@NotNull Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        String reqBody = getRequestBody(request);

        System.out.println("Inside HttpInterceptor before next()");

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        System.out.println("Inside HttpInterceptor after next()");

        return response;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the binary name is

```
type(ElementMatchers.named("okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder"))
```

You can otherwise register a listener in your builder to see if a type is processed or ignored and what its name is.